# Count number of characters between two specific characters

Tags: swift

Trying to make a func that will count characters in between two specified char like:

count char between "@" and "."  or  "@" and ".com"

If this is only solution could this code be written in a simple way with .count or something less confusing

```
func validateEmail(_ str: String) -> Bool {

let range = 0..<str.count
var numAt = Int()
  numDot = Int()

if str.contains("@") && str.contains(".") && str.characters.first != "@" {
    
    for num in range {
        if str[str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: num)] == "@" {
            numAt = num
            print("The position of @ is \(numAt)")
        } else if
            str[str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: num)] == "." {
            numDot = num
            print("The position of . is \(numDot)")
        }
    }
        
    if (numDot - numAt) > 1 {
            return true
        }
}
return false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many edge cases to what you're trying to do, and email validation is notoriously complicated. I recommend doing as little of it as possible. Many, many things are legal email addresses. So you will need to think carefully about what you want to test. That said, this addresses what you've asked for, which is the distance between the first `@` and the first `.` that follows it.

```
func lengthOfFirstComponentAfterAt(in string: String) -> Int? {
    guard
        // Find the first @ in the string
        let firstAt = string.firstIndex(of: "@"),
        // Find the first "." after that
        let firstDotAfterAt = string[firstAt...].firstIndex(of: ".")
    else {
        return nil
    }

    // Return the distance between them (not counting the dot itself)
    return string.distance(from: firstAt, to: firstDotAfterAt) - 1
}

lengthOfFirstComponentAfterAt(in: "rob@example.org") // Optional(7)
```

There's a very important lesson about Collections in this code. Notice the expression:

```
string[firstAt...].firstIndex(of: ".")
```

When you subscript a Collection, each element of the resulting slice has the same index as in the original collection. The returned value from `firstIndex` can be used directly to subscript `string` without offsetting. This is very different than how indexes work in many other languages, and allows powerful algorithms, and also creates at lot of bugs when developers forget this.

Answer (score 1):

With help from @Βασίλης Δ. i made a direct if statement for  func validateEmail that check if number of char in between are less than 1

```
  if (str.split(separator: "@").last?.split(separator: ".").first!.count)! < 1{
    return false
    }
```

It could be usefull

Comment: Do you really want to crash when there is no `.` after the `@`?

Comment: Also, are you intentionally rejecting email address from `@ibm.com`, `@aa.com`, and `@g.cn`?

Comment: I've forgot about them ill' change it to 1... also i haven't seen this question(at least not in a simple form like this) so i thought maybe someone will need this too. @RobNapier